# Wrap date to span or div

Tags: php, date

i have a php code to display day counter till now, i need to put each number into span or div like this:

```
<div class="one">1</div> <div class="two">5</div> <div class="three">2</div> <div class="four">6</div>
```

My code:

```
<?php
function dateDiff($start, $end) {
$start = strtotime($start);
$end = strtotime($end);
$diff = $end - $start;
return round($diff / 86400);
}
echo dateDiff("2010-01-30", date('Y-m-d')).' d.' ; 
?>
```

Comment: Do you need this to be returned from the function only?

Comment: can you explain what is the values in those divs respectively ?

Comment: i just need to get date count from date years before, for example from 2010.01.30, my script returns 1524 days, and now i need to put every number to div, i want to separate number to have ability to style them with css

Answer (score 2):

use `DateTime`, which is very simple

```
$d1 = new DateTime('2010-01-30');
$d2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));//use same format that was used in d1
$diff = $d2->diff($d1);

//code to display number of days into seperate digits
$str = "".$diff->days;
$size = strlen($str);
$i=0;
while($i<$size)
{
echo "<div>$str[$i]</div>";
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
$dStart = new DateTime('2010-01-30');
$dEnd  = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
```

`$dDiff` will be a `DateInterval` object so you can do this:

```
echo '<div class="year">' . $dDiff->y . '</div> <div class="month">' . $dDiff->m . '</div> <div class="day">' . $dDiff->d . '</div>';
```

I would recommend this method over trying to calculate the values yourself, since it's hard to calculate exactly how many months have passed and how many extra days are remaining after that.

The `DateInterval` object also has the property `days` with the full amount of days between the two dates. Usage: `echo $dDiff->days;`

PHP5.3+ required.

Comment: Thanx, but output looks like this: 4 2 4, this is not exact count of days from 2010-01-30

Comment: @Newcomer here 4 2 4 means 4 years 2 month and 4 days left.And this the way you asked right ?

Comment: @Newcomer krishna is correct, also updated my answer to reflect on your comment

Comment: I am very sorry! My bad! Your code is working fine, i need to output days in divs. I will fix my question

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="year"><?php echo dateDiff("2010-01-30", date("Y")) ?></div> 
<div class="month"><?php echo dateDiff("2010-01-30", date("m")) ?></div> 
<div class="day"><?php echo dateDiff("2010-01-30", date("d")) ?></div>
```

Comment: I think not. `2014 - 2010-01-30`?